# Should I transform my feature into normal distrubition before Isolation Forest

Tags: random-forest, anomaly-detection, outlier

I have a anomaly detection problem and my features are following exponential distrubition. Should I first transform my features into normal distrubition before feed into isolation forest?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use data as is for anomaly detection as the underlying data is not normal. Apart from what you asked, Isolation Forest has a problem that it has the chances of creating ghost clusters where anomaly scores would be incorrect. Hence the recent one is EIF works better.